# I need to find solutions dealing with a JSON

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

i'm developing a toolsearch who find coincidences in an input filed comparising the keywords who the user types with a JSON.

I'm doing tests with a single API about countries information and well.. it works.

The function is this:

```
getResults(keyword:string) {
return this.http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/"+keyword)
.map(result => {return result.json()
.filter(items => 
items.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()) )
   });
 }
```

But i have a problem.. The structure of the array who im trying to catch is similar to this:

```
{"status":"OK","items":[{"id":4359,"name":"Cleveland"},
{"id":6855,"name":"Ohio"},{"id":7669,"name":"Seattle"}]}
```

It's not a simple array, it's an object with two properties (items and status) and items got an array in which possitions are saved objects with two properties: id and name.

Who can i addapt my own function to deal with that JSON?

Thanks and sorry for my english

Edit:

I tried something like this

```
  getResults(keyword:string){
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
// headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
return this.http.get("http://newapi.com?q=" + keyword + "&_=" + this.nocache, options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    response =>  {
      response.items.map(item => item.name) ;
     let ciudades = response.items;
    },
    error => error => this.onError(error));
```

Comment: Yes i spent my free sunday with this. This is not my homework and it isn't my job, i'm learning, but i didn't find any solution

Comment: If you tried something out - add it to the question, so other people will be able to see what you tried and might be able to address the problems.

Comment: Ok, i'll do next time. Thanks

Comment: Don't add comments of code... update the question with the relevant information

Comment: Drop the `headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*')` from your request code. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is strictly a *response* header for servers to send. The only effect sending it in a request will have is to trigger your browser to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request, which will fail if the server doesn’t expect to receive a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` request header. The `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name API` endpoint you’re making a request to sends a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, so it supports CORS already without you needing to do anything more

Comment: The cors error was in the other api, not in countries API. Anyways this question is solved for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in your original code:

```
.map(result => {return result.json())
```

To:

```
.map(res => res.json().items)
```

Comment: So many thanks.. This actually works for me. I can't believe who i spent +4 hours trying to find a solution to this. Sigh

Comment: Beetlejuice i've another cuestion.. when i search for a province how can i know too the id who is associated to that province? I'm doing this in angular/ionic and im pretty noob. I need to find a solution to create some kind of search bar to select the provinces of that array and kept the id associated to.. i need another function?

Comment: can you help me with that? @BeetleJuice

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the call to `json()` returns the JSON that your answer describes, the following will work for you.

```
function getResults(keyword: string) {
  // const response = this.http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/" + keyword);
  return response 
    .json().items
    .filter(item => item.name
      .toLowerCase()
      .startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()));
}
```

We need to access the `items` property first. Then we can all `filter` on the array that it returns.

[Here is a demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20json%20%3D%20%60%0D%0A%20%20%7B%22status%22%3A%22OK%22%2C%22items%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A4359%2C%22name%22%3A%22Cleveland%22%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%22id%22%3A%206855%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Ohio%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20%22id%22%3A%207669%2C%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Seattle%22%20%7D%5D%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20response%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20json%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20JSON.parse(json)%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getResults(keyword%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20const%20response%20%3D%20this.http.get(%22https%3A%2F%2Frestcountries.eu%2Frest%2Fv1%2Fname%2F%22%20%2B%20keyword)%0D%0A%20%20return%20response%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.json().items%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20item.name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.toLowerCase()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20results%20%3D%20getResults(%22c%22)%3B%0D%0Awindow.alert(JSON.stringify(results))%3B) of it working with the JSON that your answer describes.

```
const json = `
  {"status":"OK","items":[{"id":4359,"name":"Cleveland"},
  { "id": 6855, "name": "Ohio" }, { "id": 7669, "name": "Seattle" }]}`;

const response = {
  json: () => JSON.parse(json)
};

function getResults(keyword: string) {
  // const response = this.http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/" + keyword)
  return response 
    .json().items
    .filter(item => item.name
      .toLowerCase()
      .startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase()));
}

const results = getResults("c");
window.alert(JSON.stringify(results)); // [{"id":4359,"name":"Cleveland"}]
```

Comment: Thanks.. I see this works but you know the way of do the same in angular? Im becoming crazy. In fact im developing in IONIC

Comment: What problem are you experiencing, @Specimen, when you try this way in Angular?

Comment: I need to translate that function to angular and i don't know how i can do this. I'm trying to declare the variables on different places but i didn't find the solution

Comment: @Specimen I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean by "translate that function to Angular."

Comment: Sorry.. Im developing on ionic and i'm trying to do the same than you do declaring variables in the class, and defining into the constructor but i cant.. For example i dont know how put this on angular way: `const json = `
  {"status":"OK","items":[{"id":4359,"name":"Cleveland"},
  { "id": 6855, "name": "Ohio" }, { "id": 7669, "name": "Seattle" }]}`;

const response = {
  json: () => JSON.parse(json)
};`

Comment: *I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean by translate that function to Angular.* Your solution won't be plug-and-play for OP because what `http.get()` returns (what your code calls `response`) is really an RxJS observable; it does not have a `.json()` method

Comment: Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option, here you go. All you have to do is iterate through the `items` array with `$.each`:

```
// say the JSON is mapped to a variable called json.
// If you need to parse the JSON, use JSON.parse()
$.each(json.items, function(index, item){
    var id = item.id;
    var name = item.name;
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1acnzgo/)

If you want a plain JavaScript solution:

```
var items = json.items;
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var item = items[i];
    alert(`ID: ${item.id} | Name: ${item.name}`);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgcseup9/)